# Can't read blogger post content using GData API

Tags: java, blogger, gdata-api

I need to read the content of some posts i'm retrieving from a blogger feed.

This code retrieves the first available post from the blogger feed

```
URL postsFeedUrl = new URL("http://www.blogger.com/feeds/" + blogId + "/posts/default");
Query postsQuery = new Query(postsFeedUrl);

Feed resultFeed = myService.getFeed(postsQuery, Feed.class);
Entry e = resultFeed.getEntries().get(i);
```

The problem is: how to get the post content?

If i use

```
e.getContent();
```

i get a `Content` object from which i don't know how to extract the real post content.

If i use

```
e.getPlainTextContent();
```

It results in

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: TextConstruct object is not a PlainTextConstruct
    at com.google.gdata.data.BaseEntry.getPlainTextContent(BaseEntry.java:358)
    at BloggerFeed.printAllPosts(BloggerFeed.java:49)
    at BloggerFeed.main(BloggerFeed.java:28)
```

How can i retrieve the post content with the GData API?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add param fetchBodies=true.